# Fill a limited number of values - tidyr Fill

Tags: r, fill, tidyr

I have a data frame and I am using:

```
df <-  data.frame(dates = seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"),as.Date("2016-01-10"), by=1)
       , category = c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5))
       , values= c(1, rep(NA,4), 5,6, rep(NA,3))) 

df %>% group_by(category) %>% fill(values)
```

but I would like fill to only carry forward a certain number of places (i.e stop carrying forward if it's too far away from the initial point). Is there a simple way of doing this without a for loop?

In this example I would like to stop filling if the date is >2 days from the last non NA point. So the values column would be

```
values = c(1,1,1,NA,NA, 5,6,6,6,NA)
```

Thank you

Comment: Pls provide an example for reproducing your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is to first `fill(values)` and then convert to NA any values that were observed after more than two days from last non-NA point (i.e. `max(dates[!is.na(values)])`).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(category) %>% 
  mutate(new_date = max(dates[!is.na(values)]), diff1 = as.numeric(difftime(dates, new_date)/(24*3600))) %>% 
  fill(values) %>% 
  mutate(values = replace(values, which(diff1 > 2), NA)) %>% 
  select(dates:values)

#Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
#Groups: category [2]

#        dates category values
#       (date)   (fctr)  (dbl)
#1  2016-01-01        a      1
#2  2016-01-02        a      1
#3  2016-01-03        a      1
#4  2016-01-04        a     NA
#5  2016-01-05        a     NA
#6  2016-01-06        b      5
#7  2016-01-07        b      6
#8  2016-01-08        b      6
#9  2016-01-09        b      6
#10 2016-01-10        b     NA
```

Note the `difftime` was giving me seconds so I manually converted to days

Comment: Just for the record. You don't have to convert seconds to days manually. Just set `units` argument to `days` in `difftime`.